# AutoCAD: Access group pivot in C#

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am writing a plugin for AutoCAD in C#.
I would like to change the position of the pivot point of a group.
It is possible to do that by mouse clicking but after deselecting  and reselecting the group, it automatically moves back to it's default position (which looks like it is the center point of the bounding box).

If I use something like...

```
private void SetBasePoint(Group group)
{
    group.AnyAvailableMethod();
    //or...
    group.AnyAvailableAttribute;
}
```

...none of the offered attributes or methods give me any solution or hint how to get there.

Does anyone have a clue how to access the pivot?

-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after working through several APIs and websites I contacted Kean Walmsley from Autodesk Developer Network and even he told me there was no direct way to get access to the pivot of a group.
So now I'm saving a user defined basepoint inside AutoCAD and whenever I need a function with a predefined pivot position I simply call my own `loadBasepoint()` -method which fits perfectly for my specific case.

Just in case someone runs into the same issue I thought I'd mention it :)